# cannot implement SecureSocial Custom TemplatesPlugin playFramework

Tags: playframework-2.0, securesocial

im trying to implement a custom views to the SecureSocial module
ive done the following (its a java project)

in the package service ive created the file CustomTemplate.scala

ive copy paste the code from http://securesocial.ws/guide/views-customization.html to that class
ive changed the class name from MyViews to CustomTemplate
and the return of the getLogin Page from  views.custom.html.login(form, msg) to  views.html.custom.login(form, msg)

the login page is a complete copy paste from the github source code

now for the problems
 1. not found: type TemplatesPlugin  -> added securesocial.controllers after the extends
 2. added the pages provider.scala.html and signUp.scala.html
 3. not found: type RequestHeader -> in login page change the `(implicit request: RequestHeader)` to `(implicit request: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader)`
 4 .story goes i get now the `type mismatch; found : play.api.data.Form[securesocial.controllers.Registration.RegistrationInfo] required: play.data.Form[securesocial.controllers.Registration.RegistrationInfo]`
resolved by adding play.api.data.Form in the login.page

this went on and on until i added all the pages
now i get the following

```
ambiguous implicit values: both method requestHeader in object PlayMagicForJava of type => play.api.mvc.RequestHeader and value request of type play.api.mvc.RequestHeader match expected type play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
```

any idea how to proceed?

Comment: i forgot to mention my securesocial version :"securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "master-SNAPSHOT"

Comment: when trying to use the different module version ,"securesocial" % "securesocial_2.9.1" % "2.0.12", im getting the following error Plugin [com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin] cannot been instantiated.